# Assign Bitbucket Server to Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

I have Gitlab account free trial i want to connect gitlab with bitbucket To migrate from Bitbucket To Gitlab .

When i Choose > New project >  Import project > Bitbucket > bitbucket.org index will appear to enter Email and Password , But i have Bitbucket installed  my Server i want to assign my Bbitbucket server URL to Gitlab to Login from gitlab and began to migrate .

I can not log in to Bitbucket.org i want to log in with my bitbucket in my server username and password .

How can assign my Bitbucket server URL to gitlab to login from gitlab ?

Comment: Does it not suffice to just host your git repo on Gitlab now instead of Bitbucket? I.e. just clone the current BitBucket git repo and push it to Gitlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The BitBucket importer currently only works with BitBucket's cloud offering (bitbucket.org) and does not work with BitBucket Server.

This is no longer the case, since GitLab 11.2 (August 22nd, 2018)

See "[**Importer for Bitbucket Server**](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/22/gitlab-11-2-released/#importer-for-bitbucket-server)":

> While GitLab has supported importing projects from Bitbucket Cloud using OAuth authentication for quite some time, such an integration with the self-hosted Bitbucket Server wasn’t available. Until now.
>
> With GitLab 11.2, it is now possible to import your projects from Bitbucket Server to GitLab with minimal effort. All that is required is to provide the server URL and your credentials. GitLab then lists all your BitBucket Server repositories, ready for import.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/11_2/bitbucket-server-import.png]

- [See documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/bitbucket_server.html),
- [see issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25393),
- [see merge-request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/20164).

Answer (score 1):

According to the GitLab documentation:

> The BitBucket importer currently only works with BitBucket's cloud offering (bitbucket.org) and does not work with BitBucket Server.

You can do the following to move the repo (but not the metadata such as pull requests or security settings):

- git clone --bare your-repo-url
- cd into the bare clone (your-repo.git)
- git push --mirror your-git-lab-url

This copies the entire repo as is to the remote repo at the URL specified.

Comment: sorry this is not useful answer , can you explain ?

Comment: Re-wrote the original now that I had the time to check on a few things